# How to get php to read xml document?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, variables

I need some php code to read this XML, and take the content of the `<title>`
 tags and declare as a `$title` variable. And the same for the `<tags>` and `<content>` as `$tags` and `$content` variables respectively.

The XML is listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<page>
    <title>Example title</title>
    <tags>example,title,page</tags>
    <content>This page has some lovely example content</content>
</page>
```

Comment: One of many similar questions: [Simple XML reading question (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074473/simple-xml-reading-question-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has been talked many times on stackoverflow, try to learn about [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php). you need to load the file and then loop inside

```
$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($data as $key => $val)
    echo "$key=>$val" . "<br>";
```

live working sample -> http://codepad.viper-7.com/6r1Tnd

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [loadXML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php). The link describes this function and gives some example code on how to use it.